# How to create my game architecture in a protocol oriented way?

Tags: swift, struct, architecture, protocols

I haven't found any good ways to design a protocol oriented item architecture for games.

Heres the first version with Structs:

```
protocol Usable {
    func useItem()
}
protocol Item {
    var name: String { get }
    var amount: Int { get }
    var image: String { get }
}
struct Sword: Item, Usable {
    var name = ""
    var amount = 0
    var image = ""
    func useItem() {

    }
}
struct Shield: Item, Usable {
    var name = ""
    var amount = 0
    var image = ""
    func useItem() {

    }
}
```

The problem with this is I have to copy paste the variables which are A LOT of code across items.

Heres the second version with Classes:

```
protocol Usable {
    func useItem()
}
class BaseItem {
    var name = ""
    var amount = 0
    var image = ""
}
class SwordClass: BaseItem, Usable {
    func useItem() {

    }
}
```

This looks pretty good, but the problem is these are reference types and I would prefer them to be value types.

What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: presumably things do have different names, amounts and images which need to be set somewhere? have you considered using an extension?

Comment: I'm thinking of parsing some JSON and setting up names, image files dynamically. In any case amount is always going to be 0 when first initialized. Protocol extensions don't store value properties unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You should create a generic struct which conforms to your protocols and which requires initialisation with default values and a 'use' closure:

```
protocol Usable {
    func useItem()
}
protocol Item {
    var name: String { get }
    var amount: Int { get }
    var image: String { get }
}
struct UsableItem: Item, Usable {
    var name = ""
    var amount = 0
    var image = ""
    let use: (Void -> Void)

    init(name: String, image: String, use: (Void -> Void)) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.use = use
    }

    func useItem() {
        self.use()
    }
}
```

Then your JSON processing would create instances with the appropriate logic:

```
var sword = UsableItem(name: "sword", image: "sword") {
     print("cut")
}
```

Comment: I just have one issue, if a certain type of item, lets say shield of holy light. when it gets damaged, it heals the user or something random. This system is a great way, but doesn't really work if I want to customize items in the future. Do you have any alternatives for that?

Comment: That should be dealt with using some other struct / class which takes the associated objects an parameters and operates on them. It also has its own logic and data, such as the time aspect which wouldn't fit as part of their data directly.